# How to show accessory input toolbar using forms in ionicframework?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

This is from the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/html5-input-types/#text) 
[image]

This is my code and output
[image]

What should be added to show the toolbar with done button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to see the Done button, you will need to download Cordova keyboard plugin: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/keyboard/

Then use this line:

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
```

Something like this:

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaKeyboard) {

  $cordovaKeyboard.hideAccessoryBar(false)

});
```

This example will work only if you include ngCordova to your Ionic project.

More information can be found here: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard

> Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar Hide the keyboard accessory bar with
>   the next, previous and done buttons.
>
> cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
>   cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);

Precisely the buttons you can see on a top image.

Comment: I don't use the keyboard plugin and it shows up on our form inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may have to be a form...so our app shows the word done in the toolbar and this is what our code looks like. I don't know for sure but I am guessing the done button shows up when there is a form to be submitted. Give it a go and let me know.

```
<form ng-submit="authenticate(user)" name="loginform" id="loginform">
                <div class="list has-header padding">
                    <div style="height: 48px;" class="item item-input">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="user.username">
                        <i class="icon ion-close-circled padding" ng-if="user.username.length" ng-click="resetUsername()"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div style="height: 48px;" class="item item-input">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password">
                        <i class="icon ion-close-circled padding" ng-if="user.password.length" ng-click="resetPassword()"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <button type="submit" class=" login button button-full button-positive">Login</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```